# msbuild using VSTS returns Error MSB4019

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to build CI/CD for Azure Data lake analytics - USQL code and when i build the code using Visual studio build option in VSTS getting the below error - Error MSB4019:The imported project "C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DataLake\MsBuild\1.0\Usql.targets" was not found.

My import statements from project file is -

And import build arguments as below - 
/p:USQLSDKPath=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/USQLMSBuild/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.180223/build/runtime /p:USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck /p:DataRoot=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)

Any help in resolving this issue will be much appreciated

Comment: Are you using a private or hosted agent?

Comment: I'm using Hosted Agent

Answer (score 0):

The targets error could indicate that the Data Lake targets are missing on your agent. I suggest you to setup a private agent, install Visual Studio on it and install the Data Lake extensions/components you have installed on your local machine.

Comment: i used Private agent instead of hosted agent but getting the below error - C:\Users\a.sivananthan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DataLake\MsBuild\1.0\Usql.targets(33,5): Error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.CompilerTask.USqlCompilerTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.CompilerTask. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.CompilerTask' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct

Comment: Install the azure datalake extension package on the build server

Comment: i have already installed the Azure Data lake and stream analytics development plug in..but im not able to see this in Extensions and updates

Comment: In my build definition i have selected Visual studio build with a private agent and build arguments as below - /p:USQLSDKPath=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/USQLMSBuild/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.180223/build/runtime /p:USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck /p:DataRoot=$(Build.SourcesDirectory). But still getting the same error as above - Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.CompilerTask.USqlCompilerTask

Comment: in my C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\ADL Tools\2.3.3000.1\U-SQLSDK i dont have this file Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.CompilerTask.USqlCompilerTask. Is this any reason why im getting this error.. Im not able to find answers for this specific problem..followed the other link and not able to find correct solution..Any help in resolving this will be much appreciated..thanks..

Comment: How to install the nuget package using Package manager..when i run the install command in package manger (VS2015) im getting the below error - Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK -Version 1.3.180223 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetNoActiveSolution,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand –

Comment: I believe you will need this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49504

Comment: i already installed this package. But do i need to link this with Visual studio 2015.Pls let me know

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo I'm getting below two errors - C:\Users\a.sivananthan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DataLake\MsBuild\1.0\Usql.targets(35,7): Error MSB4064: The "OutputAssembly" parameter is not supported by the "USqlCompilerTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property. C:\Users\a.sivananthan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DataLake\MsBuild\1.0\Usql.targets(33,5): Error MSB4063: The "USqlCompilerTask" task could not be initialized with its input parameters. Not sure where im going wrong. Let me know what changes i need to do

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps below and check the result:

1. Modify project file:

replace

```
<Import Project="$(AppData)\Microsoft\DataLake\MsBuild\1.0\Usql.targets" />
```

to

```
<!-- check for SDK Build target in current path then in USQLSDKPath in the case of command line build -->
  <Import Project="UsqlSDKBuild.targets" Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' And  Exists('UsqlSDKBuild.targets')" />
  <Import Project="$(USQLSDKPath)\UsqlSDKBuild.targets" Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' And !Exists('UsqlSDKBuild.targets') And '$(USQLSDKPath)' != '' And Exists('$(USQLSDKPath)\UsqlSDKBuild.targets')" />
  <!-- backward compatible with IDE build -->
  <Import Project="$(AppData)\Microsoft\DataLake\MsBuild\1.0\Usql.targets" Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true'" />
```

2. Install Microsoft.Azure.Datalake.USQL.SDK package
3. Specify MSBuild Arguments like this: `/p:USQLSDKPath=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/USQLMSBuild/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.3.1019-preview/build/runtime /p:USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck /p:DataRoot=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` (per to actual path)

More information: [Continuous integration made easy with MSBuild support for U-SQL (preview)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/10/24/continuous-integration-made-easy-with-msbuild-support-for-u-sql-preview/)